# Python urrllib2 throws AttributeError on add_header, but only locally

Tags: python, urllib2

I have run into a strange problem.

Simple piece of python code:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://google.com')
request.add_header('foo', 'bar')

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
print data
```

Raises AttributeError on add_header. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/path/to/bizarro.py", line 4, in <module>
  request.add_header('foo', 'bar')
 File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 229, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError, attr
AttributeError: add_header
```

This exact code works fine when I run it on a remote linux server.

Also, adding headers works using build_opener:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('foo', 'bar')]
response = opener.open('http://google.com')
print response.read()
```

It feels like it has something to do with python or windows(I'm running windows 7).
I have consulted google but no hint thus far where to look. Has anyone encoutered anything like this? Any ideas where to look for a solution?

Comment: same versions of python?

Comment: if you look in the `C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py` do you see `self.add_header` in the Request class?

Comment: It has not! Can I just add it from the Python27 source code?

Comment: post your file contents to pastebin, I will compare and see what is different, it is a standard lib so something has gotten changed somehow

Comment: urllib2.py
http://pastebin.com/VgVgKbCM

Comment: it is there and your file is identical to mine. It is a strange one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Padraic Cunningham for pointing me in the right direction!

A single line was missing from urrlib2.py. WTF? It was the declaration of add_header method.

Should be like this:

```
def add_header(self, key, val):
    # useful for something like authentication
    self.headers[key.capitalize()] = val
```

Was like

```
    # useful for something like authentication
    self.headers[key.capitalize()] = val
```

That was the only line missing in the library. I added it and the code works.

EDIT: Thinking about it, I think it's possible I deleted it accidentally myself. In the IDE (PyCharm) I could have gone into the lib with Ctrl+click on add_header accidentally and a quick ctrl+x to delete the row which I use often and there you have it.